# C# Winform radiobutton state switching

Tags: c#, winforms, events, radio-button

I need to link radio buttons, as they are not in the same container, so I wanted to add them to a list and handle their `CheckedChanged` events

```
private List<RadioButton> Buttons = new List<RadioButton>();

public void Add( RadioButton button ) {
    button.CheckedChanged += button_CheckedChanged;
    Buttons.Add( button );
}

private void button_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
   var button = sender as RadioButton;
   if( button == null || button.Checked == false )
       return;
   foreach( var btn in Buttons ) {
       if( btn != button )
           button.Checked = false;
   }
}
```

When I click a radio button it stays unchecked, any idea why?

Comment: The btn != button is probably the issue. Comparing objects for equality is different than value types.

Comment: @DougDawson I need the reference to be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shouldn't this be

```
  foreach( var btn in Buttons ) {
       if( btn != button )
           btn.Checked = false;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: np, We do it all the time.  That why code review\paired programming is really good.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a silly question, but you have the AutoCheck property set to true, correct?  If it is set to false then the radiobutton will not be checked when you click on it.

button.AutoCheck = true;

Or you can change it in the property window in the designer.